# How do I get Red5 /installer URL not to yield 404?

Tags: red5

I've performed a clean install of Red5 Media Server 1.2.2 on Ubuntu Server 18.0.4 LTS.

I can access my server via `<server ip>:5080`. I see the screen confirming red5 is installed. If I click on `demo` followed by `install`, taking me to `<server ip>:5080/installer`, I get a 404 Error from Apache Tomcat.

What could I need to change, to access this page?

Answer (score 1):

The `installer` webapp is not there anymore, that's why you get the 404. The app is no longer supported and as you've noticed, we haven't removed or fixed the link on the demo page yet.

Comment: Hey Paul, a shot in the dark, I had a website using red5 and my apps were modified versions of the broadcaster and subcriber demos. I think I had changed the flash but was still using the demo red5 java parts cuz I know nothing of java but i knew actionscript. So now years later trying to bring that app back up. I have my modified flash in place. I setup red5 running on ubuntu18 but I think I have to install the subscriber and broadcaster demo for my crap to work. Is there any way this is still possible? Any hint? There are links to githubs on bottom of start page. how to use?? Thanks!

Comment: The original broadcaster and subscriber used the oflaDemo app, if memory serves me; it should come with the latest server releases, so essentially there's nothing to install other than copying your swf and html into the proper directory on the server under webapps.